# How do I use my Jetpack Compose theme's background color in my Splash Screen resource?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I want to use my Jetpack compose Material theme background color instead of the hard-coded value in the XML resource file. Is there a way to do this? I found an answer but for the opposite [How do I use Color resource directly in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988112/how-do-i-use-color-resource-directly-in-jetpack-compose)

I have a resource file for the splash screen,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_compress_24</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.DailyTasks</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I want something like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme.background</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_compress_24</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.DailyTasks</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I wanted to do this so that when my app's theme is in dark mode, then the background color of the splash screen will be the same as the background color of my app instead of the hard-coded @color/white defined in my resource file.